# Is chat only in Meta, or are there chat spaces particular to each site?

Tags: support, chat, users

I want to chat with a user in a beta site ([Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/)) where I have over 100 reputation at the moment.  I recently lost some reputation by starting a discussion in the form of a question which was downvoted 3x; I want to avoid that in the future, but unfortunately now that I have identified a particular [user](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/2752/david-hammen) with whom I want to chat, I cannot figure out how to even begin communicating with that person.

Comment: Please forgive me for my ignorance!  I am a new SE user of less than six months.

Comment: Yes, I think so.  I don't know much about chat, but if you have over 100 rep there, you could go to https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=space.stackexchange.com, and create a room for you and @davidhammen.

Comment: There is chat, but I don't believe that user is active in chat.  It's generally not a good idea for people to invite others into chat rooms without warning; it tends to be annoying.  If there was a room that they frequented, you could always try to talk to them there, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @fbueckert, could you not just ping them like @DavidHamme'n?

Comment: @Ollie Only if they've recently been in that chat room.

Comment: Title and body of the question are totally different. In the title you ask about chat, in the body you ask about contacting a specific user. Please decide first what you want to ask, then have a proper title for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit confusing

- [Chat.StackOverflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) is for Stack Overflow users with more than 20 rep
- [Chat.Stack**Exchange**](https://chat.stackexchange.com) covers most other Stack Exchange sites and requires 20 rep across the whole network (includes SO)
- [Chat.**Meta**.StackExchange](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com) is just for Meta.SE and you need 20 rep on Meta.SE (this site)